# Html5 understanding

Tags: html, css, audio, iframe

This challenge is to make a talking comic book. Think of a simple story that can be told in four panels. Each panel will have a drawing (or digital photo) but no text. As the user clicks each panel, an audio recording “says” what text would say in a typical comic. You’ll have to use an iframe to trigger each of the four audio recordings, and each of the comic panels will really be a button to  link to the page with the panel’s audio. You can use clip art for the panels if you want, and you can enhance the story with sound effects to accompany the audio.

I'm new in html5 and for others this may be simple but I can't understand what is that panel exactly. It's like a section tag ? And how can I use the Iframe to trigger them ? 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple ways to do this. If you're going to use iframe, then you may want to create a separate html file for each panel. Each page should contain the art (img) and the audio file for that page. For example:

**panel1.html:**

```
  <img id="panel1.jpg" src="..." />
  <audio controls>
    <source src="yourfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> <!-- check out documentation to see to choose the type that is right for your file -->
  </audio>
```

And then

**panel2.html:**

```
  <img id="panel2.jpg" src="..." />
  <audio controls>
    <source src="yourfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> <!-- check out documentation to see to choose the type that is right for your file -->
  </audio>
```

Etc...

You may need to style these using CSS. Then, on your main page you will need to create your `iframe` tags, link them to the html files via the `src` attribute. Like so:

```
<iframe src="panel1.html"></iframe>
```

You will probably also want to add some CSS to display these to your liking. I would check out the documentation on `<audio>` and `<iframe>` for more options that might help you.

Also, you will want to use Javascript and/or JQuery to handle the clicking. For example, to your artwork `<img>` tags in your panel.html files, you could add a class to assign to ALL of your images. JQuery will handle events for all images with this `art-panel` class.:

```
<img src="panel1.jpg" class="art-panel" alt=""/>
```

**Handle Clicking Event**

Finally, to handle clicking on the panel, you may want to consider JQuery. Make sure to link it in your document before trying to use it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.art-panel').click(function() {
        // Stop other audio if playing
        // Play this panel's audio
        // (or however you want to handle it of course ^_^
    });

});
```

That's about as much as I can think of right now. Have fun :)